# Using a range of values in a variable to overcome line plot x and y error

Tags: r, date-range, line-plot

I am trying to plot a line plot/line graph to show the relationship between two variables. However, because the lengths of x and y variables differ just slightly, I am receiving a persistent error

```
####Getting cumulative emissions data for x-axis

ncfname1 <- "cumulative_emissions_RCP45.nc" #(1-Dimensional array)
Model3 <- nc_open(ncfname1)
get2 <- ncvar_get(Model3, "CanESM2") #Has 90 values
get2.teratons <- get2/1000 #converts all values gigatons to teratons

####Getting Model data for extreme precipitation (units of  
millimeters/day) for y-axis

Model4 <- brick("MaxPrecCCCMACanESM2rcp45.nc", var="onedaymax") #This is a  
3-Dimensional array and has 95 values

latlon <- cbind(45.525,-73.968) #specifies specific lat/lon location
Hope3 <- extract(Model4,latlon)
```

To plot

```
plot(get2.teratons,Hope3, type="l",col="black", xlab="1pctCO2 Cumulative  
carbon emissions (TtC)", ylab="One-day maximum precipitation (mm/day)",  
main="One-day maximum precipitation for CanESM2 1pctCO2")
```

This yields the following error:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 'x' and 'y' lengths differ
```

In an attempt to resolve this error, I thought that it would be best to omit the last 5 values of "Model4" to match the length of "get2.teratons", which has 90 values, I tried to following to select the first 90 values in Model4 by doing this:

```
new.data<-dplyr::between(Model4,0,89)
```

Yields this error:

```
Error: Not compatible with requested type: [type=S4; target=double].
```

I then tried this:

```
newfile<-Model4[Model4$onedaymax %in% (0:89),]
```

But I receive this error:

```
Error in .local(x, ...) : invalid layer names
```

I'm not sure what else I can do at this point, but the goal is to have both my x and y values match (90 values each, as opposed to 90 and 95, which is causing the plotting error). Unless, someone knows of another and simpler way to overcome that plotting error?

Any assistance would be extremely valuable!!!!

Thank you,

Comment: Can you please post a reproducible example?

Comment: Hi flee, thanks for your response - I'm not sure how to post a reproducible example, unfortunately, without putting the actual data used here somehow. The problem is essentially in "plot(get2.teratons,Hope3, type="l",col="black", xlab="1pctCO2 Cumulative  
carbon emissions (TtC)", ylab="One-day maximum precipitation (mm/day)",  
main="One-day maximum precipitation for CanESM2 1pctCO2")" due to x and y differing in length (x being 90 and y being 95). Thus, I would like to select a data range for y so that y can match the length of x (i.e. both 90). Does that make sense?

Comment: Is `Model4[1:90,]` what you want?

Comment: Hi Simon Woodward, Yes, "Model4" (3-Dimensional) is what I would like to use in order to somehow make it length 90 (it is currently length 95). This would allow it to match the length of variable "get2.terraton" (1-Dimensional), which is already length 90. I tried your suggestion, but the new length of the new variable is now 8550 when I use NewModel4 <- Model4[1:90,], along with the warning message: Warning message:
In .doExtract(x, i, drop = drop) : some indices are invalid (NA returned)

Is there a reason for that?